# Faster way to make dataframe from dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to make pd.DataFrame from dictionary like this:

```
x = {6: 8416, 2: 8361, 5: 8343, 4: 8326, 1: 8292, 3: 8262}
```

I want the both numbers as a rows in separate columns and add column names 'Y' and 'Z'.
I done it somehow manually but I'm searching for faster way for datasets where is not possible to do it by hand anymore

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([(k,v) for k,v in x.items()], columns=["Y","Z"])`

Comment: Another answer here which works pretty fast - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68749379/4915693

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way

```
x = {6: 8416, 2: 8361, 5: 8343, 4: 8326, 1: 8292, 3: 8262}
pd.DataFrame([(k,v) for k,v in x.items()], columns=["Y","Z"])
```

Output:

```
   Y     Z
0  6  8416
1  2  8361
2  5  8343
3  4  8326
4  1  8292
5  3  8262
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one-way:

```
 pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x, 'index', columns=['y']).rename_axis('x').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   x     y
0  6  8416
1  2  8361
2  5  8343
3  4  8326
4  1  8292
5  3  8262
```

Comment: I have posted it as an answer

Comment: @bigbounty +1  Great solution.